# Convert Vectors of C++ to C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, linked-list

I am trying to convert vector vectorName; the cpp implementation to C
Actually i have to use some of its function like vectorName.push_back(string) in C but how do i do it there is no proper implementation, and is there any way we can use c++ libraries and patch it to C code somehow, this is the idea of mine

```
typedef struct vector_ {
      void** data;
      int size;
      int count;
} vector;

void vector_add(vector*, void*);
void vector_add(vector *v, void *e)
{
    if (v->size == 0) {
        v->size = 10;
        v->data = malloc(sizeof(void*) * v->size);
        memset(v->data, '\0', sizeof(void*) * v->size);
    }

    if (v->size == v->count) {
        v->size *= 2;
        v->data = realloc(v->data, sizeof(void*) * v->size);
    }

    v->data[v->count] = e;
    v->count++;
}
```

Comment: std::vector heavily relies on C++ features, such as copy construction (and of course templates)  that C simply doesn't have. I don't think this is going to fly.

Comment: i know c dosent have these features that is why i am doing this in linked list in the first place

Comment: Do you want to implement an equivalent `std::vector<T>::push_back()` (generic) or `std::vector<SomeSpecificType>::push_back()` where you know the type of the times stored?

Comment: the main question is about the type of the data, the more secure way if to have a dedicated vector_xx for each needed type. Note you can use a macro to define the appropriate vector_xx without having to do that by  hand each time

Comment: I am trying to implement SomeSpecificType for instance i want the data type to be character @BoR

Comment: C doesn't have a notion of member functions, so you can't do `vectorName.push_back(string)` in C - at least not if you want it to behave remotely like the C++ equivalent.   Yes, a C struct can contain pointers to functions, but the usage is completely different from C++ member functions.

Comment: @Peter in the end member functions transform into functions where the first parameter is a pointer to the type, they even have their own calling convention `__thiscall`. C "member" functions will be semantically different but functionally equivalent.

Comment: @vandench  - what you're referring to is specific working of one compiler (or compiler family).  There isn't a semantic or functional equivalent in standard C.   If you're going to convert C++ code into C using extensions specific to one compiler, you'd be better off simply using a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3):

An example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEF_VECTOR(type) \
typedef struct vector_##type { \
  type * data; \
  size_t alloc_size; \
  size_t size; \
} vector_##type; \
\
void init_vector_##type(vector_##type * vector) \
{ \
  vector->data = NULL; \
  vector->alloc_size = vector->size = 0; \
} \
\
void clear_vector_##type(vector_##type * vector) \
{ \
  if (vector->data != NULL) {\
    free(vector->data); \
    init_vector_##type(vector);  \
  } \
} \
\
void push_back_vector_##type(vector_##type * vector, type value) \
{ \
  if (vector->size == vector->alloc_size) { \
    vector->alloc_size = (vector->alloc_size == 0) ? 16 : vector->alloc_size * 2; \
    vector->data = realloc(vector->data, vector->alloc_size * sizeof(type)); \
     \
    if (vector->data == NULL) { \
      /* do what you want */ \
    } \
  } \
  vector->data[vector->size++] = value; \
} \
\
type at_vector_##type(vector_##type * vector, size_t index) \
{ \
  if (index >= vector->size) { \
    /* do what you want */ \
  } \
  return vector->data[index]; \
}

DEF_VECTOR(int)

int main()
{
  vector_int v;

  init_vector_int(&v);
  push_back_vector_int(&v, 123);
  push_back_vector_int(&v, 456);
  printf("%d %d\n", at_vector_int(&v, 0), at_vector_int(&v, 1));
  printf("%d %d\n", v.data[0], v.data[1]);
  clear_vector_int(&v);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra v.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
123 456
123 456
```

Execution under *valgrind*

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==11108== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11108== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11108== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11108== Command: ./a.out
==11108== 
123 456
123 456
==11108== 
==11108== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11108==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11108==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,088 bytes allocated
==11108== 
==11108== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11108== 
==11108== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11108== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Of course you have to not forget to call  `init_vector_xx` and if needed `clear_vector_xx` and using a macro to define all do not help when you have an error at the execution because you do not have the line number, etc

Here I put all in the unique macro, in reality it is better to have a macro to define the *struct* and declare the functions and an other one to define the functions, to be able to put that in headers and sources.

> is there any way we can use c++ libraries and patch it to C code somehow

Not sure it is possible to answer to that question. Of course you can get some ideas from their definitions because they are well implemented, but you also take the risk to be submerged by a complexity you don't need int your translation.

However, if you can stay in C++ do not move to C ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a something similar to `std::vector<char>` then the equivalent `push_back(char ch)` solution proposal might be:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct vectorOfChar vector;
struct vectorOfChar {
    char *start;
    char *finish;
    char *end_of_storage;
};

vector vector_construct(void) {
    vector v = {0};
    return v;
}

void vector_destruct(vector *const vec) {
    free(vec->start);
}

char *vector_data(vector *const vec) {
    return vec->start;
}

void vector_push_back(vector *const vec, char const ch) {
    if (vec->finish != vec->end_of_storage) {
        *vec->finish = ch;
        ++vec->finish;
    } else {
        int const size = vec->finish - vec->start;
        int capacity = vec->end_of_storage - vec->start;
        capacity++;
        capacity *= 3;
        capacity /= 2;
        char *const new_area = realloc(vec->start, capacity);
        if (new_area == NULL) {
            // define how to handle out-of-memory
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        vec->start = new_area;
        vec->finish = new_area + size;
        vec->end_of_storage = new_area + capacity;
        vector_push_back(vec, ch);
    }
}

int main() {
    vector v = vector_construct();

    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
        vector_push_back(&v, c);
    }
    vector_push_back(&v, '\0');

    printf("%s\n", vector_data(&v));

    vector_destruct(&v);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```